# XmlPullParser not reach end of document

Tags: android, rss, infinite-loop, xmlpullparser

Im working on a simple Android App, which should fetch RSS feeds, read and display the information on the screen. I tried to follow the Google example while implementing the code (source: [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html)).

My code looks like that:

```
  public void fetchXML(String url, Context context) {
    try {
        URL urlObj = new URL(url);
        this.parser = this.xmlPullParserFactory.newPullParser();
        InputStream stream = getInputStream(urlObj);
        String string = this.extractStringFromInputStream(stream);
        this.parser.setInput(new StringReader(string));

        int eventType = parser.getEventType();

        while (eventType != XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {
            Log.i(TAG, "value END_DOCUMENT: " + XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT + " - my eventType value: " + eventType);
            if (parser.getEventType() != XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {
                continue;
            }
            String name = parser.getName();

            if (name.equals("title")) {
                title = readTitle(parser);
            }

            if (parser.getEventType() and!= XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {
                Log.i(TAG, "IM IN END TAG");
            }

            eventType = parser.next();
    }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "EXCEPTION: ", e);
    }
}
```

Actually, it prints me the content of the title XML-Tag, but it never stops the while-loop. The value of the eventType is always 0. It also never go into the XmlPullParser.END_TAG.

Does anyone knows what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem by myself.
It simply has been the "continue" part. When i delete it, it worked.